Stream camera feed from one Pi 4 to another using Tkinter
I am currently working on a robot that runs on a Pi 4 and is controlled remotely from another Pi 4 via a Tkinter GUI. The robot Pi and the controller GUI Pi are connected with an umbilical cable allowing Ethernet connection between the two Pi 4s.
The robot has a Pi Camera, so can controll it remotely from the GUI but I have to show the video feed on the Tkinter GUI.
Currently, I am running a bashfile on boot that gets the video feed using raspivid and sends it through Netcat to the other Pi to stream the video from one Pi to the other. Then on the controller Pi, the GUI runs a bash file that opens the video feed using MPlayer.
The bash file on the robot Pi has this code:
raspivid  -w 320 -h 240 -fps 20 -o  | nc 192.168.1.80 7000

The bash file on the controller Pi has this code:
netcat -l -p 7000 | mplayer -fps 20 -demuxer h264es -

This has been working well for me with minimal lag and good camera quality but the problem is that MPlayer opens up its own window separate from the Tkinter GUI so it doesn't look good.
Does anybody know any way of displaying the video feed through a Tkinter window/frame directly instead of using MPlayer?
I haven't been able to find anything specific

are you using Picamera2  library?

@Ankit_Gunner I am not using the camera with Python right now as the GUI is running on a different Pi than the camera. All code I am using is the one shown on the post.
